# Programmatically get Core Data entity description

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an App that uses **Core Data**. How can I get programmatically the description of an entity, i.e SQL creation code, like:

```
CREATE TABLE Cities(cityName TEXT);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? The SQLite code is an implementation detail and hidden from the Core Data API. Also there need not be a 1-1 correspondents between "entity description" and "SQLite tables", e.g. in the case of many-to-many relationships. - If (for whatever reason) you need the SQLite table structures then you have to access it directly with the sqlite API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do that, and actually, you probably DON'T want to do that, but you could do it with something like that (using FMDB https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb):

```
NSString *dbPath = @"/path/to/my/CoreData/repository.sqlite"; // use NSBundle for actual code
NSString *entityName = @"Cities";
NSString *tableName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Z%@", [entityName uppercaseString]];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
if (database.open) {
    NSString *query =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = '%@';", tableName];
    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:query];
    while([results next]) {
        NSString *sql = [results stringForColumnIndex:0];
        return sql;
    }
}
```

Of course, this supposes that your CoreData app uses a SQLite repository (the usual case).

Here is what I got for one of my entity named `FormInstance`:

```
CREATE TABLE ZFORMINSTANCE ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZDEF INTEGER, ZCREATED TIMESTAMP, ZSENT TIMESTAMP, ZIDENTIFIER VARCHAR, ZLABEL VARCHAR, ZUSER VARCHAR )
```

That entity has those attributes:

```
created
identifier
label
sent
user
```

And these relations:

```
def
roles
values
```

The mapping from the CoreData structure is:

- not obvious
- undocumented
- unsupported
- private
- subject to change

Use at your own risks

Comment: Perhaps not important in this particular case, but generally your method to build the query is prone to SQL injection. Better use a prepared statement. I think FMDB supports that as `[database executeQuery:@"SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = ?", tableName]`  or similarly.

Comment: @Martin: You are right for SQL injection. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cities" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm working on this approach to build sql creations string. But I thought that there could be an easier way to achieve this.